# MYSQL ordering by 2 variables

Tags: mysql

I have a list of leagues which are alphabetically ordered in the table, ie

- Belgium Pro League
- England Premier League
- England Championship
- Greece - Super League
  etc
  etc

etc etc

and I want them ordered

- England - Premier League
- England - Championship
- Belgium - Pro League
- Greece - Super League

I have tried

```
SELECT League
FROM Leagues
ORDER BY  'England - Premier League',  'England - Championship',  `ID`
```

and

```
SELECT League
    FROM Leagues
    ORDER BY  'England - Premier League',  'England - Championship',  `ID`
```

without any luck, they are either alphabetically which I dont want or the 2 specified are at the bottom of the list.

How would I order by, the 2 specified, followed by the rest in ID order? I have tried order by FIELD too but still without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this ANSI-SQL version:

```
SELECT League
FROM   Leagues
ORDER BY 
      CASE WHEN League LIKE 'England - %' THEN 1
           ELSE 999
      END, 
      ID
```

The CASE will handle assigning priority to the England based leagues, the rest will be sorted on ID.

Hope this resolves it.

Comment: It was almost perfect, the English leagues are now first, although in ID order, so Championship if after the others.  can the English teams be ordered specifically, and then the rest?  Is it possible to have, Case When League like England Prem then 1, Case when England Championship then 2 else 999?

Comment: Yes, you can totally do that, means you're committing to ordering those two leagues like that. Just have an extra WHEN and instead do a "=" comparison instead of a LIKE, for the exact league names. Not ideal, as you are committing to those league names, but if they dont change, might be good enough then. I just showed you one way how to organize the results, you can mix it up as you like it. If you think the answer was usefull, be sure to promote it or accept as an answer :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `field()` function:

```
order by field(league, 'England - Premier League', 'England - Championship', 
               'Belgium - Pro League', 'Greece - Super League')
```

EDIT:

If you just want the two English ones first:

```
order by (substring(league, ' ', 1) = 'England) desc,
         league
```

Comment: Hi, this would work, although there are a dozen others in the list, it was just the English 2 I wanted first, without listing every league.